# Adding 'soft link' to julia

Tags: bash

I would like to be able to open the software "Julia" by simply typing `julia` in a terminal at any location (like I can do for, say, `firefox`). Currently, I have to type

```
cd ~/julia
./julia
```

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia) I must:

Add a soft link to the julia executable in the julia directory to `/usr/local/bin` (or any suitable directory already in your path).

I don't fully understand softlinks, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

`ln -s ~/julia /usr/local/bin`

Why won't this allow me to access the contents of the `~/julia` file (including the julia executable) directly?

Comment: You had created a softlink for Julia directory inside /usr/local/bin,try to create a softlink for Julia executable file inside /usr/local/bin.

Comment: ln -s /home/$USER/julia/julia /usr/local/bin

Comment: OK, now I understand - I thought a softlink would include all the contents of the linked directory in my search, but instead it works more like a Microsoft 'shortcut' to create a 'copy' of the file or program in another place, which of course isn't a real copy but instead links back to the original and runs it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the executable `julia` is under `~/julia/` folder. Use the following command in terminal to make a softlink in `/usr/local/bin`,

```
sudo ln -s /home/<username>/julia/julia /usr/local/bin
```

Replace `<username>` with your actual username. Or,

```
sudo ln -s "$HOME"/julia/julia /usr/local/bin
```

**Note:** you need to use `sudo` to access `/usr/local/bin` as it is system directory.

**Alternate User level Method (if you do not have root access)**

You can create a folder `$HOME/bin` and put it in path, use the following commands in terminal,

```
cd
mkdir bin
echo "export PATH=\$HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now create a softlink in `$HOME/bin` as,

```
ln -s "$HOME"/julia/julia "$HOME"/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just right click on the Julia file and navigate to Make Link then copy the newly created link to anywhere on your home directory.